# Removing Minutes from Date as a Variable

Tags: date, ksh

I am writing a script in KSH and need your help to find the logic to remove minutes and seconds from the date.
If users pass 2024-12-22-16-43-40 to a variable, it should be converted to 2024-12-22-16-00-00.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to cut minutes and seconds i,e. 43-40 and putting it into a variable and then trying to subtract expression from the original date variable. But somehow it is not working.

Comment: Please post the code you have. And explain what doesn't work. Most people here will gladly help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any POSIX shell including ksh (the POSIX sh specification is actually based on ksh (a subset thereof), and the `${var%pattern}` operator that expands to the value of `$var` stripped of the shortest string matching `pattern` off its end was actually introduced by ksh in the early 80s):

```
$ date=2024-12-22-16-43-40
$ printf '%s\n' "${date%-*-*}-00-00"
2024-12-22-16-00-00
```

Here, it's more string manipulation than date manipulation that you want to do, but note that the `printf` builtin of `ksh93` can do the latter. That 2024-12-22-16-43-40 format however is not among the timestamp formats it supports by default.

You can however specify additional timestamp formats using the standard `DATEMSK` environment variable.

```
$ echo '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S' > timefmt
$ export DATEMSK="$PWD/timefmt"
$ printf '%(%F-%H-00-00)T\n' "$date"
2024-12-22-16-00-00
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like: (treat it as a string of text)

```
#!/bin/ksh
d="2024-12-22-16-43-40"
s="$(echo "$d" | cut -d- -f1-4 )"
t="${s}-00-00"
echo "$t"
```

Or, treating it as a "date/time",  read `man date`, get `date` to parse your date, and output it via `date +"%Y-%m-%d-00-00"

Comment: Standard `date` doesn't parse dates (some do, but the syntax varies greatly between implementations), but the `printf` builtin of ksh93 does.